# How to define multiple CSS attributes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any syntactical way in jQuery to define multiple CSS attributes without stringing everything out to the right like this:

```
$("#message").css("width", "550px").css("height", "300px").css("font-size", "8pt");
```

If you have, say, 20 of these your code will become hard to read, any solutions?

From jQuery API, for example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both

```
.css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" })
```

and

```
.css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" }).
```

Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are *optional*, but with CSS notation they're *required* due to the hyphen in the name.

Answer (score 1040, accepted):

Better to just use [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) even if you have 1 or more styles to change. It's more maintainable and readable.

If you really have the urge to do multiple CSS properties, then use the following:

```
.css({
   'font-size' : '10px',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```

**NB!**
Any CSS properties with a *hyphen* need to be quoted.
I've placed the quotes so no one will need to clarify that, and the code will be 100% functional.

Comment: Why on earth propose and even argue for such non-standard syntax! Just add a style  with '-' i.e. `font-size`, and it fail. If it's about prove limits, then are `$('div').css({ width : 300, height: 40 });`  valid also.

Comment: @Jonas - sorry what are you on about

Comment: If the CSS property has a dash character (ie. text-overflow) then you need to put quotes around the property. That's what rlb.usa and Jonas are talking about I think.

Comment: @redsquare would you mind changing the answer to mention the fact that the properties need to be surrounded with quotes if they have "-" in them? This is the first hit on google for "defining multiple css properties jQuery" and anyone searching it has the potential to be inconvenienced by this missing information. I happened to be.

Comment: @Accipheran apologies, done -but you should really use a class: )

Comment: You're missing a comma after 'font-size' : '10px'

Comment: @redsquare Please consider adding the following to your answer. From [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/): `For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" }) and .css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" }). Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.`

Comment: love it, pass json like object

Comment: You all can argue as much as you want. If you don't use quotes it doesn't work, regardless of the the property having a dash or not.
I don't care how many fiddles you use, on public servers doesn't work.

Conclusion: the answer is correct, but you need to use quotes.

Comment: using Jquery to define CSS means they want to change values *programmatically*.  Classes are not the way to go.

Comment: @johnktejik why not? you can have multiple classes and switch programmatically.

Comment: This is the answer I would recommend, except when you have to target dimensions dynamically, example, matching the height and width of an image with a parent element in a carousel. Applies to any dimensions you still don't know.

Comment: Why do I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," in Chrome's console?!?

Comment: Nice stuff. I would say thought that addClass doesn't always work because sometimes you want to set the properties using variables in your JS.

Answer (score 175):

Pass it as an Object:

```
$(....).css({
    'property': 'value', 
    'property': 'value'
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#properties

Comment: Javascript object, not JSON.

Answer (score 75):

```
$('#message').css({ width: 550, height: 300, 'font-size': '8pt' });
```

Comment: to get that to work you have to change some syntax on it: $('#message').css({ width : '550px', height : '300px', 'font-size' : '8pt' });

Comment: erm, thanks to all the drive-by downvoters who never read jquery documentation? numeric values are converted into pixel values automatically kthx.

Comment: Yea what's the problem here? `width: 550` is perfectly valid.

Comment: i think you could also use `fontSize` without quotes...  my question is though.... how do you set `height`, and `width`, let's say... to the SAME value....  would it be `.css({ { width, height} : 300 })`?

Comment: @alexgray there's no _direct_ way to do this, but you can set them each to the same variable: `var x = 100; $el.css({width: x, height: x});`

Comment: I just UPed ya man! This works perfect. I've seen the above methods document before, however they don't seem to work when the same css has already been declared in-line. It would replace the first value but not the next. So thank you!

Answer (score 41):

Using a plain object, you can pair up strings that represent property names with their corresponding values. Changing the background color, and making text bolder, for instance would look like this:

```js
$("#message").css({
    "background-color": "#0F0", 
    "font-weight"     : "bolder"
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the JavaScript property names too:

```js
$("#message").css({
    backgroundColor: "rgb(128, 115, 94)",
    fontWeight     : "700"
});
```

More information can be found in [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).

Answer (score 19):

please try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#message').css({"color":"red","font-family":"verdana"});
})
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `attr` along with `style`:

```
$('#message').attr("style", "width:550; height:300; font-size:8px" );
```

Answer (score 11):

Agree with redsquare however it is worth mentioning that if you have a two word property like `text-align` you would do this:

```
$("#message").css({ width: '30px', height: '10px', 'text-align': 'center'});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#message").css({"width" : "550px", "height" : "300px", "font-size" : "8pt"});
```

Also, it may be better to use jQuery's built in `addClass` to make your project more scalable.

Source: [How To: jQuery Add CSS and Remove CSS](http://www.syntaxxx.com/how-to-jquery-add-css-and-remove-css/)

Answer (score 11):

Best way is to use variable.

```
var style1 = {
   'font-size' : '10px',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
};
$("#message").css(style1);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
$(element).css({
    "propertyName1":"propertyValue1",
    "propertyName2":"propertyValue2"
})
```

Answer (score 8):

**Script**

```
 $(IDname).css({
    "background":"#000",
    "color":"#000"
})
```

**Html**

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You Can Try This

```
$("p:first").css("background-color", "#B2E0FF").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Comment: This is not a good approach dude. Its better to send user json type

Answer (score 4):

if you want to change multiple css attributes then you have to use **object** structure as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#message').css({
                   "background-color": "#0F0",
                   "color":"red",
                   "font-family":"verdana"
                });
});
```

but it get **worse** when we want to **change lots of style**, so what i suggest to you is adding a class instead of changing css using jQuery, and adding a class is more readable too.

see below example:

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .custom-class{
       font-weight: bold;
       background: #f5f5f5;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 18px;
       color:red;
    }
</style>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#message').addclass('custom-class');
});
```

One advantage of latter example over former is if you want to add some css `onclick` of something and want to remove that css on second click then in latter example you can use `.toggleClass('custom-class')`

where in former example you have to set all css with different values which you have set before and it will be complicated, so using class option will be better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('selector').css({'width:'16px', 'color': 'green', 'margin': '0'});
```

The best way is to use $('selector').addClass('custom-class') and

```
.custom-class{
width:16px,
color: green;
margin: 0;
}
```