# jquery css, css gradients

Tags: jquery, css, gradient

I'm trying to apply css gradients to a specific div using the jquery css feature and can't quite seem to get it working.  I don't have access to the style sheet and am having trouble because I"m trying to apply it several times to appease cross browser issues.  I'm just not quite sure why this isn't working, any thoughts?  Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Build your CSS.
var gradient1 = {
    "background":     "-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%, #f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient2 = {
    "background":     "-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient3 = {
    "background":     "-o-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient4 = {
    "background":      "-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%); /* IE10+ */ background: linear- 
gradient(to bottom,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"
};
var gradient5 = {
    "filter":     " progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fbfbfb, endColorstr=# f4f4f5)"
};

//Apply your CSS to the body tag.  You can enter any tag here, as
//well as ID's and Classes.
$("#service_DESCRIPTION").css(gradient1);
$("#service_FAQ").css(gradient1);

$("#service_DESCRIPTION").css(gradient2);
$("#service_FAQ").css(gradient2);

$("#service_DESCRIPTION").css(gradient3);
$("#service_FAQ").css(gradient3);

$("#service_DESCRIPTION").css(gradient4);
$("#service_FAQ").css(gradient4);

$("#service_DESCRIPTION").css(gradient5);
$("#service_FAQ").css(gradient5);

});
```

Comment: For properly formed CSS, the complete style definition would be something like "background: -webkit-linear-gradient(definition)" but in your jQuery it looks like you have the colon outside the quotes, not inside. Maybe the string's not correct, and that's why it's happening? Have you tried using Firebug to see script errors?

Comment: `.css()` takes either a key+value or a map for parameters, what he's using is just a map with a single key+value pair, which is just fine.

Comment: in which browser is this not working in? this probably won't matter but you should always have the W3C standard line in there

Answer (score 0):

In `gradient4` you have space between `linear-` and `gradient`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
; /* IE10+ */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try instead of repeating adding styles action with css jquery method to put all in the same object and do it once, like here: [How to define multiple CSS attributes in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery)

besides that, not really sure if that's the reason, but, you put ";" before closing your quotes:

```
    "-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%); /* IE10+ */ background: linear-
```

gradient(to bottom,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"

on here: "-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)**;** /* IE10+ */ background: linear- 
gradient(to bottom,  #fbfbfb 0%,#f4f4f5 100%)"

just before the comments, which you should also avoid there