# Issues with implementing multiple CSS properties

Tags: jquery

I want to change the css of an element using jQuery.

```
$('p').css({
    padding-left : '6px',
    border-left : '5px solid #555'
});
```

It does not work.

However, when i use

```
$('p').css('padding-left','6px');
$('p').css('border-left','5px');
```

it works...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing, attribute names need to be quoted when using .css()

Comment: By not having the quotes, it is interpreting `padding-left` as a **variable**, just wrap them in single quotes and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap the properties (style attribute) in qoutes ('' or "").

This is because they contain a dash (-).

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WshgS/)

```
$('p').css({
    'padding-left' : '6px',
    'border-left' : '5px solid #555'
});
```

Comment: sweet stuff, thank you. you see, I referred to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery and there they do not have width and height in quotes''...I guess it is because of the hyphen...

Comment: Right. From api.jquery.com/css: "Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. ... Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name."

Comment: Correct, if you just wanted to add padding (does not contain a dash) instead of padding-left, you could avoid the qoutes. Some however consider it best practice to always wrap in qoutes. That way you always avoid these kind of situations :)

Answer (score 3):

Better to use this way:

#### [CHECK THIS OUT IN FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NFfd9/)

```
$('p').css({
    paddingLeft : '6px',
    borderLeft : '5px solid #555'
});
```

in css we use with hyphen `-` separated all lowercase and enclosed in `""` single or double quotes. This way in js/jQuery:

```
    'padding-left' : '6px',
    'border-left' : '5px solid #555'
//--^-----------^----------------------here
```

While in js all the css properties are accessible in camelCase this way:

```
    paddingLeft : '6px',
    borderLeft : '5px solid #555'
//--^^^^^^^^^^------------------------this way
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not defining them within quotes in the first piece of code.

```
$('p').css({
    'padding-left' : '6px',
    'border-left' : '5px solid #555'
});
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just missing quotes

```
$('p').css({
    'padding-left' : '6px',
    'border-left' : '5px solid #555'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('p').css({
    'padding-left':'6px',
    'border-left':'5px solid #555'
});
```