# jQuery: ScrollTop animate header div class

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div class="header">` which I want to be able to animate after the page has been scrolled 300px. I tried using the following script:

```
$(body).scroll( function() {
var value = $(this).scrollTop();
if ( value > 300 )
    $(".header").css("height", "220px");
else
    $(".header").css("height", "120px");
});
```

But nothing seems to be working...

The `<div class="header">` is a fixed element at the top of the page, and I wonder if I can add more than one css argument, unlike `$("div").css("one css-argument", "value")`? (**This has been solved**)

**Edit:**
I want the header to adjust it's height and font size when the page has been scrolled more than 300px.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery

Comment: Explain what exactly you want to achieve and add http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(body)` is wrong unless `body` is a variable defined somewhere else.

What you actually should to use though is `$(document)`

### Updated

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (value > 300) $(".header").css({height:220, fontSize:40});
    else $(".header").css({height:120, fontSize:20});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/XyCjz/1/)