# setting background size using css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div container on which i have placed two more div's (say 1 & 2) for placing the content . I have set different ids for the div's and on clicking the link( of div 2) i am changing the background image of the background div. I am trying to set the background-size as cover to occupy the whole screen width but only the upper part of the image is getting displayed. Here is the code which i am using to set the background size for the div.

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //autoOpen: false,
        $(".span12").css('background-image','url(../images/assorting_2.jpg)','background-size','100%');
<script>
```

I could have posted the images but i am unable to post it as i have less points.

Comment: CSS `background-size: cover;` http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: get your full code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: You need to pass an object to the `css` method for multiple styles

Comment: You got three answers now select the most helpful one by clicking on the mark under the votes.

Comment: Didn't one of the answers work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".span12").css({
    'background-image':'url(../images/assorting_2.jpg) no-repeat',
    'background-size':'cover'
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery) for using multiple jQuery CSS properties. And [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) for using background cover.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$(".span12").css({
                   'background-image':'url(../images/assorting_2.jpg) no-repeat',
                   'background-size':'100%'
                 });
```