# Is it possible to have two success callback functions with a jQuery.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Is this possible?**

Once my jQuery.post is successfull instead of only having one success callback i have two.

*For example*

Once my form has successfully posted the data an empty div called "#msg" is given style and content **AND** an empty div called "colour-block" is given style.

**Code so far**

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest1.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {
 $('#msg').html("<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax.....</div>");

     }
   });
});
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Things I've tried and have not worked!**

*Adding another callback*

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest1.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {


 $('#msg').html("<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax</div>");

 $("#colour-block").html("<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>bla bla</div>");
     }
   });
});
```

Using The Promise interface

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
  var ajax = $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'indextest1.php',
        data : $("#form1").serialize()
    }).done(function(response) {

 $("#msg").html('<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax while we go to work on your behalf, we\'ll keep you updated with information on our results and if you have any questions then we welcome your calls or emails on 078675675446 or isaaclayne@southwestcarfinder.co.uk</div>');

 $("#colour-block").html('<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax while we go to work on your behalf, we\'ll keep you updated with information on our results and if you have any questions then we welcome your calls or emails on 078675675446 or isaaclayne@southwestcarfinder.co.uk</div>');
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just update your second div in the same function?

Comment: i don't know, possibly. How would i go about that? like this? $('#msg' && '#color-block').html I've only recently started using/learning JavaScript so not too sure. I've looked at the api documentation and it doesn't mention anything like this.

Comment: oh would i just add a new line? $('#colour-block').html............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do both:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest1.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {
         $('#msg').html("<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax.....</div>");
         $('.colour-block').css({/*css styles here*/});
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok it would seem adding a second line kills the whole jQuery and stops it actually running.

Comment: @DanCundy Double check for semicolons, ending parentheses, ending quotes, and other syntax.  It should work.  Also, make sure you know what the syntax is for jQuery's .css().  It is al little different than pure CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery

Comment: There shouldn't be any extra semicolons, ending parentheses, ending quotes, etc as i only added one extra line, but obviously changing to my needs.

Comment: @DanCundy Try adding alert('running'); at different intervals to see where the jQuery stops running.  This will narrow down which lines may be suspect.

Comment: It's ok, you were right. Turns out the thing that was killing it was the use of double quotes.

Comment: For me your answer is the easiest and simplest answer to implement, and was really all i was looking for. So thank you @zsaat14

Comment: @DanCundy Just came here to tell you: If the javascript stops, you can look in the *console* of chrome and firebug (even IE!) and it tells you were the parse error is, on which line! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use the promise and `done`, `fail` and `always`, you can add as many as you want to, and you can do as much as you want to inside each of them

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'indextest1.php',
        data : $("#form1").serialize()
    }).done(function(response) {
          $('#msg').html("<div style='border: 1px solid black; padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; width:437px; border-radius: 8px; background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;'>Now sit back and relax.....</div>");
          $('#msg2').text('something else');
          $('#msg3').css('color', 'red');
    }).done(function() {
          $('.class').text('another callback')
          $('.class').append('<p>Not sure why you would need it ?</p>')
    });

    ajax.done(function() {
         $('.class2').txt('This is the same')
         $('.class3').txt('you can store it in a variable')
    });

    ajax.fail(function() {
         // this fires if something goes wrong
    });

    ajax.always(function() {
        // this always fires, both on success and failure
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey adeneo, I was just about to find anything for "scope of deferred object jQuery". What puzzles me is, if I have several AJAX calls, how can I know where the resolve gets send to? Since you cannot name the deferreds, at least not with the inbuild deferred, right? But is there a scope, like in any variable for the deferred?

Comment: @dollarvar - The deferred is returned from the function, so it doesn't really have a name that you can reference, but you can just set it to a variable, like in the answer above, or return it somewhere where you can catch it etc.

Comment: Ah, I get the variable thing, did not look at your code, just wanted to see deferred used. ;) However, what do you mean with return? How do you return the deferred from `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @dollarvar - you can return it, like in a function for instance, see this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/3Q42S/

Comment: Yeah, nice, thanks. So just for the record: it gets *automatically* returned. ;) Nice.

Comment: Yes, calling $.ajax, $.post or any ajax function now returns a promise object that can be used this way.

Comment: What is btw against the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, says it returns only: jqXHR! They need to add it -> http://jsfiddle.net/3Q42S/2/!

Comment: After research your answer was actually probably the correct answer with syntactically and according to the api it is the was you should do it, however after several failed attempts to implement it i just went with adding an extra callback. Which worked. However thank you for your detailed and correct answer, I however am lazy. All the best.

Comment: Pff, ok, to you too! @adeneo For the record again: It returns the whole [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/?s=deferred) object. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your second div in the same function.

You might also try to externalize your CSS, and give your inner divs some ID (or class, as you wish) to style them :

```
success: function(response) {
    //Create the inner div with the appropriate id, for css styling
    var msg_inner = $('<div>',{id:'msg-inner', html:'Now sit back and relax...'});  
    //Same thing for your colour-block div  
    var colour_block_inner = $('<div>',{id:'colour_block-inner', html:'Blah'});    

    $('#msg').append(msg_inner);
    $('#colour-inner').append(colour_block_inner);    
}
```

With the following CSS externalized:

```
#msg-inner{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding:15px 50px 15px 20px; 
    width:437px; 
    border-radius: 8px; 
    background:#D3EDD3 url(img/accepted_48.png) no-repeat 450px center;
}

#colour-block-inner{
    /* Your future style here */
}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance/inexperience, what are the benefits of externalisation? To me that seems like an over complication. Also i have tried like you have said by adding a second but it seems to kill the ajax completely.

Comment: @DanCundy That's the whole point of CSS, separate the style from the content ; concerning the 'ajax kill', could you elaborate by providing the JS error (open your browser's inspector for that)?

Comment: i'm using firebug and it would seem there is no error? where am i looking in the console? I would seem after various tests that it just only accepts one "success" action, when the code is written like this. adeneo's answer is perhaps the only way to do it?