# how to "replace" css Properties with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

with JQuery how would you change a CSS property like (in this example from **left** to **right**)
I found that .css("left") could be used to retrieve the value, then I could write a function to set the .css("right"), but is there an easier (more compact) way to do it ?:

```
#set { left: 400px; bottom: -200px; }
```

to

```
#set { right: 400px; bottom: -200px; }
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define multiple CSS attributes in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery)

Comment: ok guys thanks for the downvotes, I maybe didn't explained my point correctly... I didn't want to use Avempace's solution with addClass and removeClass (because I have a bunch of #set (#set1 to #setxx) and didn't want to duplicate the values). Felix's solution corresponds to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

```
var left = $('#set').css('left');
$('#set').css({
    right : left,
    left: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: Better to use `auto` as the initial value of `left` property. Using `left: 0` may expand the absolutely positioned elements horizontally.

Answer (score 5):

Use classes and change the class.

You can find how in the question [jquery change class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452778/jquery-change-class-name)

so your css will look like:

```
.set_left { left: 400px; bottom: -200px; }
.set_right {right  400px; bottom: -200px; }
```

With jquery you just change the class.

```
$("#set").removeClass('set_right').addClass('set_left');
```

or

```
$("#set").removeClass('set_left').addClass('set_right');
```

Answer (score 1):

To Read

```
$('object').css('CSSKEY')
```

To Write

```
$('object').css('CSSKEY','NEW VALUE)
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Your alternate method as suggested, is to use .AddClass and .RemoveClass - It provides a cleaner markup

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/
http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pv8vz/)**

You could do something like this:

```
$("#set").css({"right" :  0, "left" : "auto"});
```

Alternativley, you could use `addClass`, and set the styles in the CSS, and using jQuery, just call `addClass("your-class")`