# multiple styles with $(this).css jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying the below but it doesn't work.

```
 $(this).css('border-bottom', '2px solid red', 'padding-bottom: 26px');
```

But this works:

```
 $(this).css('border-bottom', '2px solid red');
```

Any suggestions on best way to implement both style attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define multiple CSS attributes in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper javascript notation { } for multiple styles eg.

```
$(this).css({
    border-bottom:'2px solid red',
    padding-bottom: '26px'
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Comment: answer is wrong. fix it and i'll remove the downvote. you don't pass in two separate objects, but rather one object with the css properties.

Comment: woops my bad, got it now

Answer (score 1):

you can pass in an object to `jQuery.css()` method

```
$(this).css({ "border-bottom": "2px solid red", "padding-bottom": "26px" });
```

you can see more here

[jQuery .css() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

I suggest that for future reference you bookmark the manual.

[jQuery Api Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).css({ "background-color": "red", "border-right": "5px solid green" });
```

Quite simple.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Put the styles as properties in an object, using DOM property style names:

```
$(this).css({ borderBottom: '2px solid red', paddingBottom: '26px');
```

or CSS style names as strings:

```
$(this).css({ 'border-bottom': '2px solid red', 'padding-bottom': '26px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(this).css('border-bottom', '2px solid red');
$(this).css('padding-bottom', '26px');
```