# Why css background jQuery code is not working jQuery set multiple CSS values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to add background with jQuery but this code is not working

```
$("#search").css({'background':'url(imageurl) no-repeat center center;width:32px;height:32px;'});
```

only below code is working

```
 $("#search").css({'background':'url(imageurl) '});
```

i want to implement this with jquery

**background:url(spinner.gif) no-repeat center center;width:32px;height:32px;**

> `**At least add the reason for downvote..........**`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define multiple CSS attributes in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery)

Comment: @kristjanreinhold i want to set the background height and width not element.

Comment: CSS property to set width/height to background is [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: @RakeshSojitra you are setting the css propertiesto element.

Comment: @QaisarSatti : Ok I have added answer. Please see that. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like below

```
$("#search").css({'background': 'url(imageurl) no-repeat center center','background-size':'32px 32px'});
```

OR

```
$("#search").css({'background': 'url("imageurl") no-repeat scroll center center / 32px 32px'});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put each CSS rule in its own property of the object. Try this:

```
$("#search").css({ 
    'background': 'url(imageurl) no-repeat center center',
    'width': '32px',
    'height': '32px'
});
```

Better still, put those rules in to a class in your stylesheet and use `addClass()` instead. This is much more preferable as it separates the CSS logic from the JS.

Comment: but it set the height and width of element not the background.

Comment: Well, yes. That's what `height` and `width` do. If you want to set the scale the background, use `background-size`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size