# Fullscreen image background Bootsrap3 carousel refuse to diplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a static slideshow with Bootstrap3 carousel that works fine and my aim is to make it dynamic. I can't really figure out while the images is not displaying whereas the captions do.

This html is directly bellow the body tag, before any other content, as specified:

```
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data- ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    </div>
</div>
```

And a javascript function:

```
function loadBanners() {
    var json;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "BannerServ",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            json = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.each(
                $.parseJSON(json),
                function(index, arrayObj) {
                    var imageName = arrayObj.image;
                    var caption = arrayObj.title;

                    var $cssStyle = "{ background: url(" + imageName + ") no-repeat center center fixed;\
                                    -webkit-background-size: cover;\
                                    -moz-background-size: cover;\
                                    -o-background-size: cover;\
                                    background-size: cover; }";


                    $('<div class="item"><div class="carousel-caption">' + caption + '</div></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                    $('.item:nth-child(' + index + 1 + ')').css($cssStyle);
                });
            $('.item').first().addClass('active');
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 1000 * 10
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Please I need help to get the image rendered.

Comment: This is probably related to the Bootstrap JS initializing before your images are ready. Try loading or initializing the Bootstrap JS AFTER success on your ajax call, when ALL images are loaded.

Comment: I did this but it still not displaying: complete: function(){
                               
                            $('.carousel').carousel({
                              interval: 1000 * 10
                            });
                   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your style object ($cssStyle) try using an actual object instead of a string:

```
var $cssStyle = { "background": "url('" + imageName + "') no-repeat center center fixed","-webkit-background-size": "cover","-moz-background-size": "cover","-o-background-size": "cover", "background-size": "cover" }
```

jQuery's .css() function accepts an object as the parameter when updating multiple fields.

Also see: [How to define multiple CSS attributes in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery)

Comment: Your answer really helps though, now i can see the first image displayed while the other two do not. could it be from here: $('.item:nth-child('+index+1+')').css($cssStyle);? i need to update the generated items with the new style.

Comment: I have modify the code in ajax success to this and it works seamlessly:                                           
                                         var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
                                         var captions = $('<div class="carousel-caption">'+caption+'</div>');
                                         $(item).append(captions);
                                         $(item).appendTo('.carousel-inner').css($cssStyle);